# Script showing file type?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, mime-type, file-type

I want to make a script that shows what type of file is

for example :

```
./file.sh haha test lala ssss

haha --> file

test --> directory

lala --> symbolic link

ssss --> executable
```

Im trying to do like this but I dont get the same result ...

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function check_symboliclink
{
echo "Write symbolic link"
read something
find $something -type l 
echo "$something  symbolic link";
}

check_symboliclink
```

Is there someone have better idea to do like the example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `file` command.

Example:

```sh
c0rp@c0rp: file file_1 file_2 file_3
file_1 ASCII text
file_2 ASCII text
file_3: symbolic link to file_2
```

**UPDATE**

If you can't use `file` command here is another solution.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ -d $var ]; then
        echo $var " - > is a directory"
    fi

    if [ -f $var ]; then
        echo $var " - > is a file"
    fi

    if [ -h $var ]; then
        echo $var " - > is a symbolic link"
    fi

    if [ -x $var ]; then
        echo $var " - > executable"
    fi
done
```

In this script i use `for var in "$@"`, where `"$@"` means **all passed arguments**. So using `for` you can loop through all passed arguments

You can add another check if you want, read [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

for example, if you want to add check `file is a socket`:

just add same if block before `done` word:

```sh
            if [ -S $var ]; then
                    echo $var " - > is a Socket"
            fi
```

I change only condition `[ -S $var ]`

Comment: Is there anthor way to get it without using command file ?

Comment: You only want to show this 4 points? (file, directory, executable, link)

Comment: yes, without using command file

Comment: I update answer. But what do mean by saying 'without using command line'?

Comment: OMG!! Thank you very very very much. You are my hero :)

Comment: Please note that `-x` is not ideal test of determining whether a file is executable. Directories also can have executable bit set. `[ -x /etc/ ] && echo "YES"` will print "YES", even though technically it's not an "executable file".  It would be better to nest the if statements, such that one cane check whether a regular files is also executable

Answer (score 0):

#### Showing Unix filetypes

The way this question is presented it appears as the user is trying to display type of a file in [Unix filetype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types) sense. For such purpose, one doesn't need a script, since there already exist utilities that are capable of displaying such information.

In particular, `stat` command is well suited for such purpose. By default, `stat` shows long output with plenty of information, but we can use `-c`, `--format`, or `--printf` (note that it interprets backslash escape symbols) options to achieve desired output. For example,

```
$ stat -c '%n: %F' /etc/passwd /etc/resolv.conf /etc                        
/etc/passwd: regular file
/etc/resolv.conf: symbolic link
/etc: directory


$ stat --printf '%n: %F\n' /etc/passwd /etc/resolv.conf /etc                
/etc/passwd: regular file
/etc/resolv.conf: symbolic link
/etc: directory
```

Another command which we can use is `find`, which  has `-printf` option, but differs in conversion specifiers (the `%<letter>` symbols) and the fact that it outputs filetype in letters (see the `man find` for filetype to letter correspondence):

```
$ find /etc/passwd /etc/resolv.conf /etc -prune  -printf "%p:%y\n"          
/etc/passwd:f
/etc/resolv.conf:l
/etc:d
```

Of course, if there is a need, we can always make use of `[` or `test` command, but that'll require a little more work; however this way we don't have to rely on anything external;  it's a portable way, although probably not ideal.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

check_filetype(){
    if [ -f "$1" ];then
        if [ -h "$1" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$1: symbolic link"
        else
            printf "%s\n" "$1: regular"
        fi
    elif [ -d "$1"  ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$1: directory"
    elif [ -c "$1" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$1: character device"
    elif [ -p "$1" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$1: named pipe"
    elif [ -S "$1" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$1: socket"
    fi
}

for arg
do
    check_filetype "$arg"
done
```

And that's how it would work:

```
$ ./checkft.sh /etc/passwd /etc/resolv.conf /etc test.fifo /dev/tty1              
/etc/passwd: regular
/etc/resolv.conf: symbolic link
/etc: directory
test.fifo: named pipe
/dev/tty1: character device
```

## Showing file content

If we wanted to get detailed information about the file type as far as contents are concerned, there's two ways to approach things. One, via [mime-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#mime.types) and the other - via [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), the first few bits of a file. While mime-type is originally existed for the purpose of determining filetype on the internet, nowadays many desktop applications rely on querying mime-type information for correctly displaying icons of files and opening them with proper applications.

For that purpose, there exists `mimetype` command:

```
$ mimetype /etc/ /etc/resolv.conf  /etc/passwd test.fifo                          
/etc/:            inode/directory
/etc/resolv.conf: inode/symlink
/etc/passwd:      text/plain
test.fifo:        inode/fifo
```

And for performing tests with "magic numbers" we'd use `file` command:

```
$ file /etc/ /etc/resolv.conf  /etc/passwd test.fifo                              
/etc/:            directory
/etc/resolv.conf: symbolic link to ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
/etc/passwd:      ASCII text
test.fifo:        fifo (named pipe)
```

which also can do `mimetype`'s job:

```
$ file --mime-type /etc/ /etc/resolv.conf  /etc/passwd test.fifo                  
/etc/:            inode/directory
/etc/resolv.conf: inode/symlink
/etc/passwd:      text/plain
test.fifo:        inode/fifo
```